# Why are some "duplicate" messages within the question body?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[image]

Why are some "duplicate" messages within the question body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was how the system was in the old days.

While I was not around back then, I asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280798/323179) on the other meta.

Keep in mind that editing it out is not an option. It needs to be opened and re-closed in order for the new banner to take effect.

I made [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507181/possible-duplicate) that lists posts like that.